# Custom back button in Navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

Im trying to move the navigation controllers "back button" to the toolbar at the bottom. I have added a `UIBarButtonItem` to the toolbar. And the new back button works correctly.

[image]

However I'm having trouble implementing the menu that shows up when you long press on the back button of a `UINavigationController`.

I need to get an array of the navigation titles so that I can populate the menu. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array of view controllers on the navigation stack through its `viewControllers` property. Then store the viewcontrollers title in a array like this:

```
let artTitles = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.map({$0.navigationItem.title})
```